# compare two files using loop to see what strings are not in both files

Tags: text-processing, files, grep

```
i=$(cat /etc/icinga/devices.d/xlcdw/full)

if IP in grep -q $i /etc/icinga/devices.d/xlcdw/xlcdw-endpoints.cfg;
    echo "Already configured"
  else
    echo $IP
fi
```

I'm trying to see whether the hosts I have already configured in the .cfg file are present in the file named 'full.' Of course the above code doesn't even run. I'm grepping for their IP addresses.

Comment: the [`comm`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500787/comparing-two-files-in-linux-terminal) command can do what you are looking for.

Comment: *strings are not in both files* - how that?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not going to work. the file "full" is one IP address per line. The .cfg file contains all kinds of alphabetic text in addition to IP addresses.

Comment: I need to iterate over the 'full' file to see if the IPs inside it (one per line) are also in the .cfg file.

Comment: Here is one entry of hundreds in the .cfg file:

define host {
    host_name                        JAJA-HDX
    use                                    generic-host
    alias                                   JAJAStamfordHarbor02-006
    address                             192.168.10.9
    hostgroups                        jaja-hdx8k
    register                             1
}

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the strings _might_ be in both files. That's what I'm checking.

Comment: Whatever that configuration entry you've added as a comment is supposed to look like is anyone's guess. Please put it in the question where it can be seen easily (and you can format it rationally, too).

Comment: Pasted here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24403816/

Hundreds of such entries in the .cfg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take your pieces of information out of the comments:

> the file "full" is one IP address per line. The .cfg file contains all kinds of alphabetic text in addition to IP addresses.

and

> I need to iterate over the 'full' file to see if the IPs inside it (one per line) are also in the .cfg file

So you want to iterate, which your script does not.

Try with a for loop:

```
for IP in $(cat /etc/icinga/devices.d/xlcdw/full); do
  if [[ `grep -c $IP /etc/icinga/devices.d/xlcdw/xlcdw-endpoints.cfg` > 0 ]]; then
    echo $IP already configured
  else
    echo $IP missing
  fi
done
```

Adapt that to your needs (which I don't fully understand)

Comment: @user189395 Did this work for you? Is there still an open issue as you left the question in unanswered state?